# Automatically generated SQL code throws type mismatch

Tags: sql, ms-access, append, ms-access-2010

My problem is that I would like to make an append query in Ms-Access 2010. I tried to realize it in query designer, but it throws an error:

> Type mismatch in expression

See the generated code below:

```
INSERT INTO Yield ( ProcessName, Sor, Lot, 
ProcessCode, Outgoing, DefectReason, DefectQty, ModifyQty )

SELECT Process.[ProcessName], Sor.[Sor], Qty.[Lot], Qty.[ProcessCode], 
Qty.[Outgoing Date], Qty.[Defect Reason], Qty.[Defect Qty], Qty.[Modify_Qty]

FROM (Sor INNER JOIN ProcessCode ON Sor.[SorID] = ProcessCode.[SorID]) 
INNER JOIN (Process INNER JOIN Qty ON Process.[ProcessID] = Qty.[ProcessID]) 
ON ProcessCode.[ProcessID] = Process.[ProcessID];
```

The tables and the attributes are all existing. The ID numbers are indexes, the Quantities are numerical, the 'ProcessName', 'Sor', 'Lot', 'ProcessCode', 'DefectReason' attributes are strings.

What could be the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That could be the only field you don't mention: Outgoing. It must be of data type `Date` if [Outgoing Date] is so.

Comment: @Gustav I tought about that but I put some faith and hope OP already check that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the Yield table did not have the listed attributes. I thought that if some of the listed output attributes are not included in the output table, Access automatically creates the missing new attributes. I was wrong. The output table has to contain the attributes (rows), new attributes cannot be inserted into it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Looks ok. The best advice is divide it in smaller pieces.

http://importblogkit.com/2015/05/how-do-you-eat-an-elephant/  .

Try this:

Remove the `insert` part. Just try the `select` to make sure the join are working properly. If this fail the problem is on the join fields

Then, Put the `insert` again, but instead of putting table fields from the `SELECT` use default values. `''` for strings and `0` for numeric and put the right alias for column name. That way you make sure your data is bringing the right data type. If this fail then one of the field isnt really a string or a number. Like gustav suggest probably a `DATE`

If that work then try to put one table field each time until you find the one causing the problem. Maybe one field doesnt support null or is receiving a bigger value than supported.